# Cant connect to TFS 2010 in another domain

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I have domain A and domain TEST.
I have a test server on domain test. I installed succesfully TFS on that server.
I added users from domain TEST,(our prod domain), to the tfs server.
I added them as local admin, ad admin, tfs admins, everything you can imagine.

I cant connect, I get this error.

I am sure the password is correct.

---

Microsoft Visual Studio

> TF31003: Either you have not entered the necessary credentials or your
>   user account does not have permission to connect to the Team
>   Foundation Server at http://10.0.0.152:8080/tfs. Click the Use
>   different credentials link below, or ask your server administrator to
>   add the appropriate permissions to your account.

Comment: When you say you added users from Domain A to TFS how did you do that?  If TFS is not on Domain A you can't add domain A users to TFS unless you have a trust relationship between domains.  Do you mean you created TEST domain accounts for your users to use?  Did you create local machine accounts on the TFS box for them to use?

Comment: I created the users in domain test, then I went to the tfs server and added those users to the groups I mentioned above.

Comment: actually I wrote something wrong, the users I added are from domain TEST.   I am trying to connect from a computer in domain A but using TEST\user

Comment: then I'm stumped, that works for me, I do it all the time.

Comment: Are you trying to connect as MYTFS\User? If you would just use User it could be resolved as the domain user and can not be validated. Edit: Ok, you wrote that at the moment I wrote this comment.

Comment: strange thing, when I used test\administrator it connects fine from computer in domain A.  I wonder if I am missing something in the user? adding user to a special group in the domain or a local group in tfs server? or maybe even in tfs security and group configuration I am missing something? any comment is welcome.

Comment: I tried to connect to TFS Web access with the same user, it didnt connect.

Comment: I did something that worked, I added the user TEST\User to the Domain Administrator group in the test AD and now it worked.  But I dont want to do that.  There should be an easier way with other group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way to enforce credential usage when hopping on trusted domains is to use cmdkey.  I use it all the time to connect to a TFS server from a non-domain computer.  Just do the following:

Open a Cmd Prompt and run:

```
 cmdkey /add:<yourserver> /user:TEST\user /pass:ThatUsersPassword
```

Then next time you connect to that server, it shouldn't even ask you for the other user's creds.

Comment: great, thanks.  Makes things much easier when developing in a dev VM.

Comment: This is the simplest solution I have ever encountered to anything.  Worked the first time! :)

Answer (score 1):

When this sort of thing happens, I like to pull up [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and see if there's anything I can see in the data. It's SOAP/XML, so it's human readable. Obviously, the user info will be encrypted, meaning this might not actually get you anywhere, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but more strange - it wasn't stable - sometimes login was successful. I think, I found source problem in client's Internet explorer proxy settings! I changed proxy settings (turned on) and all warked now (at least for this time =) )